# Firebase Error auth/admin-restricted-operation after createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

Im getting an Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation) error after trying to sign up with email. (In settings of my project i have creating users with email allowed.) It could be something in my project settings? I was searching internet to solve that problem like for hours so please help, im really new to firebase.

```
import React, {useContext, useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import { auth } from '../firebase';
import { createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const AuthContext = React.createContext()


export function useAuth(){
    return useContext(AuthContext)
}

export function AuthProvider({children}) {
    const [currentUser, setUser] = useState();
    
    function signup(email, password){
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, user => {
            setUser(user)
        })

        return unsubscribe
    }, [])


    const value = {
        currentUser,
        signup
    }

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    )
}

import {React, useRef, setError, useState} from 'react' 
import { useAuth } from '../contexts/AuthContext';

function SignUp() {
    const emailRef = useRef();
    const passwordRef = useRef();
    const passwordConfirmRef = useRef();
    const {signup} = useAuth();    

    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        await signup(emailRef.value, passwordRef.value)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" inputRef={emailRef} required></input>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" id="password" inputRef={passwordRef} required></input>
                <label for="email">Pasword Confirmation</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" inputRef={passwordConfirmRef} required></input>
                <button type="submit" >Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SignUp

import * as firebase from "firebase/app"
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";


const app = firebase.initializeApp({
...
})

export const auth = getAuth()
export default app
```

[image]

Comment: Is the email/password provider enabled in the Firebase console?

Comment: Yes it is, in my auth sectioni

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So uhh i solve that...

- I forgot to add

```js
export const auth = getAuth(***app***);
```

i had

```js
export const auth = getAuth();
```

- and i used inputRef instead ref in form

Explaining:

It was restricted for admins due to input i was sending it was (undefined, undefined) because of using inputRef instead ref.

Answer (score 11):

You saved me! Everywhere else people are incorrectly saying to enable anonymous authentication as the correct solution for [auth/admin-restricted-operation]. Of course, that is wrong.

Enabling anonymous authentication works at first, so everyone thumbs it up, but it only works because anonymous authentication doesn't require an email and password to be sent. Trouble comes later when we realize we aren't able to log in with the email and password we used to signup when we simply enable anonymous auth without addressing the actual problem.

The real answer is **we are not sending email and password correctly**, as in your case, so email/password auth says "no, only admins can do that kind of magic".

**We have to check our sign-in data**. That's the answer.
Thanks so much!

Comment: Im glad that i could help you :>

Comment: in my case, there was a typo in the request data.

Answer (score 2):

Please check if you're passing the right parameters to the **createUserWithEmailAndPassword** method.
In my case, my callback function was not receiving any text to be passed to setStateMethod. I was using my code like this

```
onChangeText={() => setEmail()
```

**What I Did?**
Just pass text to the method like this:

```
      onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33707612)

Answer (score 0):

**2024 - Solution**
I had to update my firebase settings to allow signups.
`Firebase -> Authentication -> Settings -> Enable create (sign-up)`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can not provide email and password when you call the signup(email, password) function from the others file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).