# React Native, Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation) fix?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication

```
const handleSignUp = () => {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((re) => {
            console.log(re);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    );
};
```

This is the signup function that I've implemented for email and password authentication using Firebase authentication. The error that I'm getting is,

```
Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).
```

This happens every time I run this function and the firebase authentication tab does not show the new user. Been stuck on this error for quite a while now and am unable to fix it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: where is auth value code ?

Comment: Is the email/password provider enabled in the Firebase console?

Comment: @hongdeveloper yes the email/password provider is enabled.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase Error auth/admin-restricted-operation after createUserWithEmailAndPassword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215748/firebase-error-auth-admin-restricted-operation-after-createuserwithemailandpassw)

Comment: @hongdeveloper nope I tried doing that but it didn't work

Comment: @ameyalambat128 any explanation as to why this happens? i found out that if i use the createUserWithEmailAndPassword as it is and i don't wrap it in another function, it works as intended.