# How to solve Firebase authentication issue?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make email and password authentication on my personal project using Firebase, but when I submit form I'm getting an error:

```
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/admin-restricted-operation).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:136:55)
    at _fail (assert.ts:65:9)
    at _performFetchWithErrorHandling (index.ts:177:9)
    at async _performSignInRequest (index.ts:195:27)
    at async createUserWithEmailAndPassword (email_and_password.ts:230:20)
    at async handleSubmit (Signup.tsx:13:7)
```

This is AuthContext.tsx component:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { auth } from "../firebase";
import {
  createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
  signInWithEmailAndPassword,
  signOut,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";

interface IUserData {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

interface IContext {
  signUp: any;
  logIn: any;
  logOut: any;
  user: any;
}

const AuthContext = createContext<IContext | null>(null);

export function AuthContextProvider({ children }: any) {
  const [user, setUser]: any = useState({});

  function signUp({ email, password }: IUserData) {
    return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function logIn({ email, password }: IUserData) {
    return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  }

  function logOut({}) {
    return signOut(auth);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentUser) => {
      setUser(currentUser);
    });
    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  });

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ signUp, logIn, logOut, user }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

export function UserAuth() {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
}
```

This is my Signup form component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserAuth } from "../../context/AuthContext";

export default function Signup() {
  const [email, setEmail] = React.useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = React.useState("");
  const { user, signUp }: any = UserAuth();

  const handleSubmit = async (e: any) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      await signUp(email, password);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <img
        src="img.jpg"
        alt="background-image"
      />
      <div>
        <div className="max-w-[450px] h-[500px] mx-auto bg-black/75 text-white">
          <div className="max-w-[320px] mx-auto py-16">
            <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">Sign Up</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="w-full flex flex-col py-4">
              <input
                type={"email"}
                placeholder={"Email or phone number"}
                className={"p-3 my-2 bg-gray-700 rounded"}
                onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              />
              <input
                type={"password"}
                placeholder={"Password"}
                className={"p-3 my-2 bg-gray-700 rounded"}
                onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              />
              <button className="bg-red-600 my-4 py-3 font-bold">
                Sign Up
              </button>
              <div className="flex justify-between text-sm text-gray-500">
                <p>
                  <input type={"checkbox"} className="mr-2" />
                  Remember me
                </p>
                <p>Need help ?</p>
              </div>
              <p className="py-8">
                <span className="text-gray-600">
                  Already subscribed to Filmeon?
                </span>
                <Link to={"/login"} className={"mx-2"}>
                  Sign In
                </Link>
              </p>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

As I mentioned before I'm getting an error while trying to submit form. After reading the forums - some advise to enable anonymous authentication but this is not what I need, I need to do this through email and password. I would be grateful for help in solving the error

Comment: Right before you call `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, log the values of `email` and `password` and check if they actually have values. That's what this answer explains: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69262052/209103

Comment: I saw this answer but didn't find a solution for myself in it. Can you tell me exactly what I need to do? It says that before calling the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function, I must register an email and password, but how do I do this before calling this function?

Comment: function signUp({ email, password }: IUserData) {
    if (email && password) {
      return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }
  } // That is not working

Comment: You'll need to log the values of email and password right before you call Firebase, and check if they actually have values. Without that, it's impossible to say more than the error message does.

Comment: I read the documentation again... It's not clear how to register values before calling the createUserWithEmailAndPassword function. Thanks for the answers

Comment: Logging the values of your variables has nothing to do with Firebase, but is a step in debugging the (and pretty much any) problem. Add `console.log('email: '+email+', password: '+password);` on a line before the call to Firebase and check if the output is what you expect it to be.

Comment: I got this:   email: undefined, password: undefined.

Comment: Also I have this response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "ADMIN_ONLY_OPERATION",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "invalid"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Comment: If those values are `undefined`, then the response you get from Firebase is correct as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69262052/209103) that I linked in my first comment. The problem seems to be [accessing the values from a form in an onsubmit handler in react](https://www.google.com/search?q=accessing+the+values+from+a+form+in+an+onsubmit+handler+in+react). If the previous questions about that topic don't help you solve it, you might want you isolate the problem to just be about the React/HTML form interactions, without using Firebase: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I did a check. The data I enter in the email and password field is stored in the email and password variable and displayed correctly in the console. Perhaps you are right and the mistake is that I am sending invalid data, but why is this happening if the variables store what is needed? I suspect that when handleSubmit is called, some magic happens and the signUp function does not work as it should and for some reason returns undefined...