# Angular signup with Firebase giving error

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase-authentication

Trying to connect an Angular signup form with Firebase , but it gives this error

```
  **FirebaseError: Firebase: This operation is restricted to administrators only. 
  (auth/admin-restricted-operation).**
```

I have enabled the authentication in the Firebase console.
Signup Ts

```
 onSubmit(form: NgForm){
    this.authservice.registerUser({
      email: form.value.email,
      password: form.value.password
    });
```

HTML code for signup, I have used material UI -

```
   <form fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" fxLayoutGap = "10px" #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit) ="onSubmit(f)">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input 
            type="email"
            matInput 
            placeholder="your email address" 
            ngModel="email" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" 
            email
            required
            #emailInput="ngModel"
            >
            <mat-error *ngIf="emailInput.hasError('required')">email is empty</mat-error>
            <mat-error *ngIf="!emailInput.hasError('required')">email is invalid</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field hintLabel = "at least 6 characters">
            <input 
             type="password" 
             matInput 
             placeholder="your password" 
             ngModel = "password" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"
             required                
             #pwInput="ngModel"
             >
           
        </mat-form-field>
        <button type="submit"[disabled]="f.invalid">Submit</button>
     </form>
```

Service TS

```
 registerUser(authData: AuthData){
        this.afAuth
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(authData.email, authData.password)
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result);
                this.authSuccessfully();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });      
        
        this.authSuccessfully();
    }
```

Comment: Most likely the `authData.email` and `authData.password` values that you pass to `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` are empty. Log them to check that is the case, and (if so) work backwards to determine how that happens. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69215748/firebase-error-auth-admin-restricted-operation-after-createuserwithemailandpassw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try having auth data as seperate parameter like

```
registerUser(email, password) {
  // Rest of the code
}
```